# UML class diagram for Remote Interface

Tags: java, interface, uml

There are 2 interfaces A and B which implement remote methods. How can I implement another interface which aggregates interfaces A and B? Or is there any other way to do it?
Eg:

```
public interface A extends java.rmi.Remote
{
    //function declns
}

public interface B extends java.rmi.Remote
{
    //function declns
}

public interface C extends java.rmi.Remote implements A,B
{
}
```

gives me error saying there's a syntax error on implements

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface A extends java.rmi.Remote
{
    //function declns
}

public interface B extends java.rmi.Remote
{
    //function declns
}

public interface C extends A,B
{
}
```

Note that interface `C` does not need to directly extend `java.rmi.Remote` since it extends `A` and `B`, both of which themselves directly extend `Remote`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface A {
  public methodA();
}

public interface B {
  public methodB();
}

public interface C implements A,B {
  public methodA();
  public methodB();
}


+----+     +-----+
| A  |     |  B  |
+----+     +-----+
  ^           ^
  |           |
+----------------+
|       C        |
+----------------+
```